# Back up AppEngine database (Google cloud storage?)

Tags: database, google-app-engine, backup, cloud, storage

I have an AppEngine application that currently has about 15GB of data, and it seems to me that it is impractical to use the current AppEngine bulk loader tools to back up datasets of this size. Therefore, I am starting to investigate other ways of backing up, and would be interested in hearing about practical solutions that people may have used for backing up their AppEngine Data.

As an aside, I am starting to think that the Google Cloud Storage might be a good choice. I am curious to know if anyone has experience using the Google Cloud Storage as a backup for their AppEngine data, and what their experience has been, and if there are any pointers or things that I should be aware of before going down this path.

No matter which solution I end up with, I would like a backup solution to meet the following requirements:

1) Reasonably fast to backup, and reasonably fast to restore (ie. if a serious error/data deletion/malicious attack hits my website, I don't want to have to bring it down for multiple days while restoring the database - by fast I mean hours, as opposed to days).

2) A separate location and account from my AppEngine data - ie. I don't want someone with admin access to my AppEngine data to necessarily have write/delete access to the backup data location - for example if my AppEngine account is compromised by a hacker, or if a disgruntled employee were to decide to delete all my data, I would like to have backups that are separate from the AppEngine administrator accounts.

To summarize, given that getting the data out of the cloud seems slow/painful, what I would like is a cloud-based backup solution that emulates the role that tape backups would have served in the past - if I were to have a backup tape, nobody else could modify the contents of that tape - but since I can't get a tape, can I store a secure copy of my data somewhere, that only I have access to?

Kind Regards
Alexander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options here, though none are (currently) quite what you're looking for.

With the latest release of version 1.5.5 of the SDK, we now support interfacing with Google Storage directly - you can see how, [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview.html). With this you can write data to Google Storage, but to the best of my knowledge there's no way to write a file that the app will then be unable to delete.

To actually gather the data, you could use the [App Engine mapreduce API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/). It has built in support for writing to the App Engine blobstore; writing to Google Storage would require you to implement your own output writer, currently.

Another option, as WoLpH suggests, is to use the Datastore Admin tool to back up data to another app. With a little extra effort you could modify the remote_api stub to prohibit deletes to the target (backup) app.

One thing you should definitely do regardless is to [enable two-factor authentication](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html) for your Google account; this makes it a lot harder for anyone to get control of your account, even if they discover your password.

Answer (score 1):

The bulkloader is probably one of the fastest way to backup/restore your data.

The problem with the AppEngine is that you have to do everything through views. So you have the restrictions that views have... the result is that a fast backup/restore still has to use the same API's as the rest of your app. So the bulkloader (possibly with a few modifications) is definately your best option here.

Perhaps though... (haven't tried it yet), you can use the new Datastore Admin to copy the data to another app. One which only you control. That way you can copy it back from the other app when needed.

Comment: Do you have any metrics about the speed of the bulk loader for backing up large data sets? My experience is that it would many take days to backup 15GB of data.

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt: in my experience. If you give it enough threads than you can upload ~1GB in 30 minutes, but the bulkloader tends to crash with that much data and threads. So I don't think there is a good solution available out of the box.