# Google App Engine - prohibitively slow and expensive backup and restore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backup, restore

After working on several GAE apps, some of which are being used for production, I have come to the conclusion that on this platform, backing up your production data is slow enough and expensive enough for us to transition to some other cloud based technology stack.

In one of our production apps, we have around a million entities with an average size per entity of 1KB.  So the total size of the data is around a GB which should not be a big deal, right?  Here is the output of the bulkloader tool after fetching the entities from the app engine with default options:

> [INFO    ] 948212 entities (608342497 bytes) transferred in 47722.7
>   seconds

That is almost 13 hours.  So if we wanted to set up an hourly backup system for our production data, that would be way beyond impossible with the current GAE toolset.

The cost is another story.  I tried using the datastore admin to copy entities to a different app which i thought we could use for backup.  I first set the budget to $2 per day which quickly ran out at around 5000 entities, then i increased the budget to $10 per day which ran out again without being anywhere close to replicating the million entities.

I obviously dont intend to spend $100 every time i need to back my 1 GB data up neither do i want to wait for hours (or even days) just so that my data would be backed up.  So either I dont know something or Google App Engine is currently just an impractical way to write scalable production quality apps of meaningful size that can be easily backed up and restored.

Is there a fast and cost-effective way to backup your data from a GAE app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very good question.  I was looking around for this issue and I think Google Cloud Storage(**experimental**) will be a better fit for backup data because of following reasons, I took these from Google site to help you get some information.

*Google App Engine provides an easier way to read from and write to Google Cloud Storage objects , which allows applications to create and serve data objects. These objects are stored within buckets in Cloud Storage but can be additionally accessed by Google App Engine applications through the Google Cloud Storage API. You can interact with the Google Cloud Storage API using the RESTful interface or through the Google Cloud Storage Python API for Google App Engine applications, which is discussed in this document.*

**About pricing:**
Free quota: 5GB storage(this is great for your case)
Paid quota: First 0 - 1TB   $0.085/GB/month

[Introducing Google Cloud Storage](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview.html#Introducing_Google_Storage)

Comment: GCS in no way solves the problem of backing up your AppEngine Datastore. One would still need to query the whole database and then push it to GCS.

Comment: You can use MapReduce as Nick Johnson suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747453/back-up-appengine-database-google-cloud-storage.

Comment: So, is GCS the accepted solution to the cost problem, or is there something else available?

Answer (score 5):

Bet you've found a solution by now Yasser, but for anyone else ending up here from Google, here's an updated answer:

The backup option in the appstore admin has been upgraded to support both datastore and cloud storage. It also uses mapreduce to do the backup, which makes the query much lighter on the system.

Answer (score 2):

As per [GAE billing doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html), you should be paying for the following:

Datastore:

```
1 query = 2 read operations
1 Mio entity queries = 2 Mio read operations
100k read operations = $0.07

Cost: 1M entities queried = $0.14
```

Bandwith:

```
Price: $0.12 / Gb  
Cost: 1Gb data with 50% overhead (network + metadata) = 1.5Gb x $0.12 = $0.18
```

Backend instances:

```
Price: $0.08/h smallest instance
Cost: 1h = $0.08
```

**Total cost: `$0.40`**

It seems that bulkloader is very inefficient. You might reconsider writing your own backup code. This should be easy if you only have one kind of entities without relationships.

Comment: I mentinoed that the cost i was incurring was when i was writing the data back to a backup datastore using their own admin tool so the write cost will be applicable in that case, not the read cost.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the majority of your cost is for writing the data into another app rather than reading the data from your app. Depending on your data model, the cost for writing an entity to the datastore could easily reach 100x the cost of reading it on the first place.

Since backups rarely got restored anyway, I would suggest you to store your backup in the Blobstore instead. Pickle the entities that you are going to backup into byte streams, split the stream into chunks of 1 MB each, and [write them all into the blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).

Writing data to the blobstore still cost you datastore writes, but based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685324/cost-of-storing-a-file-in-datastore-vs-blobstore), it appears that you are only charged 12 write ops per storing a blobstore entity. Assuming each pickled entity are sized ~2KB, and each entity cost 100 write ops per storing to the datastore, this represents ~99.97% savings in write cost.